# GUI update and delay in program flow

Tags: javascript, user-interface, delay

`txtA` is an HTML text area.

Javascript:

```
addTxtA = str =>  document.getElementById("txtA").value+=str+"\n";
 
function delay(sec){
    let start = now = Date.now();
    while((now - start) < (sec * 1000))  now = Date.now();
}      

window.onload = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i<5; i++ )  addTxtA(i);   
    delay(2);
    for (let i = 5; i<10; i++ ) addTxtA(i); 
}
```

Program starts a delay and then prints `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9`.

If I change `addTxtA()` to `console.log()` it prints as I expected `1-2-3-4` (delay) `5-6-7-8-9`.

I want the program to print to the GUI with delay between 4 and 5.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The delay does happen where you expect it to happen, but the browser is not able to render anything before all synchronous code execution has finished.

You need to refactor the code to asynchronous execution, e.g.:

```
const delayAsync = function( sec ){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        setTimeout( () => { resolve(); }, sec * 1000 );
    })
}

const runAsync = async function(){
    for (let i = 0; i<5; i++ )  addTxtA(i);
    await delayAsync(2);
    for (let i = 5; i<10; i++ ) addTxtA(i);
}

window.onload = function() {
    runAsync();
}
```